# How to enable gzip?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, gzip

I would like to enable GZIP throughout my whole website. What would be the best way to do it? Would it be through .htaccess?

Any pointers on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/21447/apache-gzip-configuration/21483#21483

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for mod_deflate.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html